# How can I find and highlight clusters of values within a certain range of each other in r or python?

Tags: python, r, file, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I have a list of numbers **(all larger than 10,000,000)** and I want to find clusters of numbers within **5,000,000** of one another (these correspond to columns in a manhattan plot for SNP mutations in genes).

Is there a way to do cluster analysis on the list so I can write a file where: 
`If [i]+1 < [i]+5,000,000`.

That it will highlight those values in the file? I have it as excel file for now but can change format. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to "cluster" the data for this? Isn't *sorting* enough?

Answer (score 0):

You will get several potential answers here. I like the `data.table` package because it is fast and has many built in operators that are useful. In this case, we can use the `shift()` parameter to make the comparison between observation `i` and observation `i + 1`. You could break this up into multiple steps, but consolidating all your logic into one row looks like this:

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(int = sample(10000000:100000000, 10000, replace = TRUE))

dt[, highlight := ifelse(shift(int,n = 1, type = "lead") < int + 5000000, "highlight", "no highlight")]
#show how many rows fit our criteria defined above
table(dt$highlight)
#> 
#>    highlight no highlight 
#>         5524         4475
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>